# How to know the which language is used developing the website except the extension like .php,.html,..net

Tags: url

If we want to know that which language is used to developed the particular website
like http://stackoverflow.com.Except the extension like .php,.net,.html etc
thank you

Comment: Why do you want to know?  Why does it matter to you?

Answer (score 1):

In the general case, you cannot, unless you can get an insider to tell you.

Sometimes error messages can be revealing, but that's just another vague heuristic.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a chrome extension called Chrome Sniffer, which allows you to inspect web framework / CSS and JavaScript library running on current browsing website.

Comment: thanx for replying me.I am using firefox then....

Answer (score 1):

FireFox has an extension Wappalyzer :

<kbd>[FireFox Extension URL](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/wappalyzer/)</kbd>

When you visit website it detect information related to website.

Wappalyzer has an extension in Google Chrome also